# Remove one IP from DNS entry with multiple IPs

Tags: dns, bind

I was going to add a new DNS entry on my server, but I had a typo and accidentally added the IP (10.0.55.41) to an existing entry.

```
[root@DNS1 ~]# nsupdate
> update add DB2.domain.com. 3600 A 10.0.55.41
> send
```

Now when I use nslookup I see two IPs

```
[root@DNS1 ~]# nslookup DB2
Server:         10.0.2.209
Address:        10.220.2.209#53

Name:   DB2.domain.com
Address: 10.0.2.210
Name:   DB2.domain.com
Address: 10.0.55.41
```

I am trying to remove the extra IP (10.0.55.41) but I get update failed: REFUSED error.

```
[root@DNS1 ~]# nsupdate
> update delete DB2.doamin.com
> send
update failed: REFUSED
```

How can I remove the extra IP (10.0.55.41)?

Comment: Can't you edit the configuration file directly and restart the daemon?

Comment: You can try `nsupdate -l` to use the local key or add the `update-policy` and `allow-*` of your config to the question.

Comment: I edited the file and removed the IP then restarted the service but still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to remove it manually from the zonefile.
(Don't forget to increase the serial) and reload it: `rndc reload domain.tld`

Edit:
I forgot: Because it is a dynamic zone you have to freeze it before manually changing with `rndc freeze domain.tld` and unfreeze it afterwards with `rndc thaw domain.tld`

Comment: I removed it from the zone file, incremented the serial number, and restarted the service but it still shows up.

Comment: Your TTL is 1 hour can you check again and reconfirm?

Comment: In my experience just restarting the service does not always work - in fact it sometimes prevented bind from starting again

Comment: Freezing a zone causes any dynamic changes that are in the zone's journal file to be merged in the main zone data file. Just stopping the BIND service before editing the zone data file won't necessarily do that. And if the journal is not merged, the changes in the journal file will be again applied on top of your edits when BIND starts again, possibly undoing them.

Comment: " but it still shows up."  how do you test? you do not say. you need to make sure to query directly the authoritative nameserver and not some cache.